# Why is my PHP code returning these kind of errors when adding data to MySQL db?

Tags: php, mysql

Code

[image: This is my code]

DB

[image: This is my db]

This is the error I get when I try to add data in the db

[image: This is the error I get when I try to add data in the db]

Comment: PLEASE post code as text, in the question, not links to images

Comment: The column can't be NULL. The error message tells you. Remove the column from the listing and the NULL from the list of values. Also parameterize that `update` query.

Comment: sorry about the picture and not the code, I had some trouble putting it

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **Unfortunately, we can’t run your screenshot as code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your table `produs2`: the `id_produs` field doesn't have the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute. Then, when you try to insert with id=null, no automatic numeric id is autogenerated.

To fix this, run this query in PHPMyAdmin:

```
ALTER TABLE `produs2` ADD `id_produs` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: great! don't forget mark the answer like correct and up arrow

Answer (score 0):

Make id_produs auto_increment and in line 76 in inserare.php neither include id_produs nor "null" in the insert statement because it is trying to insert null value to a primary key field.